# get the student rank of joined table records laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, rank

I have 2 tables users and score, where the scores table `user_id` references users table `id`.

I need to get the rank of the student based on their score and district, the code I tried is:

```
 $myrank=DB::table('score')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','scores.user_id')
    ->selectRaw('SELECT 
users.fname,scores.score,users.district,scores.paper_id,scores.user_id,
    FIND_IN_SET(scores.score,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( scores.score ORDER BY 
scores.score ASCE)FROM scores)AS rank FROM scores)')->get();
```

I am not sure how to achieve my goal so the above code is just pieced up from what i understood. any help  will be much apreciated. thanks.

Comment: Why not using relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Gabriel could you give me an example on how to use it please

Comment: I really want to give you good example but i can't just explain everything here. The document itself explains clearly : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: @Gabriel yes i already  have those codes. what i dont understand is how to access a specific record within the model for example i need the rank how do i get it through the model

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/retrieving-data-using-eloquent-relationships